# Nominative / accusative - what to use with preposition "als" and constructions like "John the engineer"?

Tags: preposition, accusative

> Sie halten Johannes **der** Ingenieur als **der** wichtigste Fachmann ihrer Firma.

I don't know if I used the two "der" articles well.

In the sentence "*Sie halten den Mann*" the accusative is obvious, but I'm not sure what to use here, and why.

Or perhaps it's possible I'm not building the sentence well all together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you mean is

> Sie halten Johannes, **den** Ingenieur, **für den** wichtigsten Fachmann ihrer Firma.

Also in this sense we have an object, which requires the accusative. Only the subject can be a nominative.

The term "Johannes, der Ingenieur" can, of course, be used in the nominative case, like

> Johannes, der Ingenieur, ist der wichtigste Fachmann der Firma.

But in your sentence, it's the object.

Comment: For a verb that takes the konjunktion als - could one here convey a very similar meaning betrachten? "Sie betrachten Johannes, den Ingenieur, als den wichtigsten Fachmann ihrer Firma"

Comment: It sounds a little awkward, I don't think you would say it like that. Grammatically it is correct, though.

Comment: @DavidHall 'Betrachten' is not wrong, but you'd rather use  'ansehen': Sie sehen Johannes, den Ingenieur, als den wichtigsten Fachmann der Firma an. There is however a slight difference: 'jemanden für etwas halten' can express the narrator's notion that 'they are mistaken / taking J. for something he isn't.'